# How to fix "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" warning?

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex

I have this small .tex file.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}


\setlength{\droptitle}{-3.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\squad}{\hspace{0.5em}}

\author{vladgovor77771}
\title{Some article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textbf{Task 1} \newline
Task description: \newline

\end{document}
```

When compiling, it warns about line

```latex
\textbf{Task 1} \newline
```

With the following message:

"Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)".

How do I fix this?

Comment: See: [How to properly code a TeX file, or at least avoid `badness 10000`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51722/187997) for more information.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue, I solved it by removing any `\newline` or `\\` at the and of every sentence that had nothing textual below.

For instance, two examples that causes that problem:

```
An example. \\
This is well used. \\
This line will cause the error. \\

(I'm a new paragraph) \\
Because there's nothing directly underneath.\\
The last line does NOT require a "newline".

This is a thid paragraph. \\
:D
```

The same is true for figures or similar

```
This is a line.
Putting a "newline", as here, before a \begin will cause the error. \\
\begin{figure}[h]
....
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick and nice solution is to use package `parskip`, and instead of using `\newline` or `\\` for line breaks, simply insert an empty line

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip} %% <-- added

\setlength{\droptitle}{-3.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\squad}{\hspace{0.5em}}

\author{vladgovor77771}
\title{Some article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textbf{Task 1}

Task description:

\end{document}
```

The warning will be gone.

---

By the way, to know why it happened, refer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334246/85946) on TeX Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of forcing an underfull box with `\newline`, you could simply leave an empty line to start a new paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}


\setlength{\droptitle}{-3.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\squad}{\hspace{0.5em}}

\author{vladgovor77771}
\title{Some article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\textbf{Task 1} 

Task description: 

blabla

\end{document}
```